# errors found when I install and import pyautogui?

Tags: key, controls, mouse

I am working a python assignment on windows 10 and want to install and import pyautogui from libraries but there is an error which is related to  DISPLAY

I hope the pyautogui function can import with no errors so that I can continue execute  the codes

Comment: Please show your error, "DISPLAY" isn't very clear.